# How do you handle multiple forms in WordPress plugin development?

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, plugins, action

I'm transitioning from CodeIgniter to WordPress.  Still trying to wrap my head around WordPress plugin development... seems pretty easy, but one thing I can't figure out is:  where do I send the form data?  In CodeIgniter, you could simply create another method in the controller and point the form action there, but it seems WordPress plugins are a little different.

Comment: Well thanks for that, very helpful.  I haven't accepted anything recently because no answers have helped.  But thanks a lot.

Comment: Acceptances made, 1 question removed.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how your plugin is generating the form. Typically you do it by registering a shortcode, something like [my_form] that you can insert into a page or post where you want the form to appear.

In your plugin code the form action can be blank -- simply reload the same Wordpress page. Your form info. will be in the global $_POST and your plugin can then process the data.

So your plugin shortcode function would have something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['my_plugin_form_field'])){
 /* code to process the form info and generate a message on screen 
 }

else{
/* the form hasn't been submitted yet so here is the code to display it
}
```

Comment: Okay sounds good.  So I'll just put a hidden field in all the forms identifying the form and going from there.  Thanks.

Comment: Check out the wp_nonce documentation -- built-in tool for generating random, one-time use tokens for securing forms: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_nonce

Comment: I had a brief look at it, still unsure how to validate it but I'll google it or look for some other usages.

Comment: If you want to post the code you're working with I'll see if I can help you polish it off.